# Cut region out of bash input

Tags: bash, readline

Say that you have entered the following command into your terminal emulator:

```
sudo apt-get apple pie install hamster
```

You run it and realise your brain fart. You placed the package names `apple` and `pie` before the install subcommand. In this case you can reformat the command to be correct through the following commands:

```
C-p M-b M-b C-k M-b M-b C-y SPC
```

Or you can watch [this recording on asciinema](https://asciinema.org/a/4Slgne5YdkCFW64SgGRHeKFTs).

But, there's possibly another way to solve this problem: Instead of cutting out the last part of the command and putting it in the middle, which is only feasible in some cases, one could perhaps select a region around `apple pie` and cut that.

So my question is simply: Is it possible to select a region like in emacs to be cut and pasted?

Comment: This is a bit late now, but just to clarify, do you mean `M-b`? `M-p` doesn't do anything in my readline and it's not bound to anything by default in emacs.

Comment: Yes that's right. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there is a function in the READLINE library for this, named just like the emacs equivalent, `kill-region`. But in order to use the key we first have to unbind it from a function defined elsewere:

```
stty werase undef
```

We can then bind the key to the function as we wanted:

```
bind '"\C-w":kill-region'
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that by default in readline you use `M-Space` to set the mark (not `C-Space` as is more typical for emacs-ish keybindings).

Comment: Also useful: `bind '"\ew": copy-region-as-kill'` & `C-y` + `M-y` works as in Emacs & `C-_` is for `undo`.

Answer (score 0):

Users of the other *one true editor* can `set -o vi` and then use. E.g.  `d2w$p`